# Why my jaxrs APIs has the application name as application path?

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly, openapi, resteasy

I created a simple version API with rest-easy and wildfly, everything should works but the application path has the name of my project:

- My version API return the version number from my `pom.xml`: The URI should be `http://localhost:8080/version`

  but to acces it this is `http://localhost:8080/projectName/version`.
- To acces to the open api file : The URI should be `http://localhost:8080/openapi`

  but this is `http://localhost:8080/projectName/openapi`

I tried to extend Application to set the `@ApplicationPath("/")` but it's not working, it just allowed me to add element on the application path

example: `http://localhost:8080/projectName/test/...`.

How can I set the application path to the root (`/`) and remove the `projectName` ?

JaxRSActivator class:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRSActivator extends Application {

    public JaxRSActivator()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

VersionFacade class:

```java
@Path("/version")
@Tags
public interface VersionFacade {
    @GET
    @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Operation(summary = "Application version", 
    responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", 
                    description = "Version number",
                    content = @Content(mediaType = TEXT_PLAIN, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)))})
    String getVersion();
}
```

web.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  
    <!-- public API -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>public</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/openapi.json</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/version</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

openapi-configuration.yaml file

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
openAPI:
    info:
        version: '0.0.1'
        title: API config file
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Tomcat and your WAR file is named 'projectName.war'. The name of the WAR becomes the context name and the application (including REST resources) need to be accessed with the context path, i.e. '/projectName' (otherwise 404). If you don't want the project name to appear in URL, you need to deploy directly in the 'ROOT' directory of Tomcat (deploying to ROOT is not recommended, usually a redirect is used to target the application). "All the above, assuming you are indeed using Tomcat"

Comment: I'm using Wildfly, but yes it might come from the wildfly configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jboss wildfly use the Web module name (projectName.war) as default context root. To set it you need to:

- Add the `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` file in your Web module:

  (if you don't package your app in an EAR file)

```xml
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <!-- Set context root to / -->
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

- Or add the `META-INF/application.xml` file in your EAR:

  (if you package your app in an EAR file)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd" version="8">
  <display-name>projectName-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <!--My Web module -->
      <web-uri>projectName-ws.war</web-uri>
      <!-- Set context root to / -->
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <!-- other EJB module -->
    <ejb>projectName-core.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

If you use Eclipse, careful it sometimes don't publish your `application.xml` so you need to put it manually in your Wildfly `standalone/deployments` folder.